# Speed up a program's installation?

Tags: installation, ssd, cpu

i have an Intel Core i7 4790 @ 3.60 GHz , kingstone 500 GB SSD , 32 GB of RAM.
im trying to install a game(Grand theft auto 5) and the ETA says it will take 6 hours to install. the problem is that it uses 8% of my CPU and only 10% of my SSD. the problem isn't with my hardware but its with the program not using my full computer power. is there a way to speed up the process?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55997/discussion-on-question-by-faisal-ahmed-speed-up-a-programs-installation).

Answer (score -1):

Well, you don't specify if your CPU is i3, i5 or i7 - but it's a 4th gen, so really I would doubt that your problem has anything to do with your processor - only case I could imagine is if all of your processing power is consumed by background tasks, in which case you can try setting upping the priority for the task at hand, like this:

[image: Set process priority using the task manager]

Comment: Why did this get a downvote?

Comment: I wasn't the downvoter, but your answer doesn't hold merit. If the problem was due to background tasks clogging the system, then the CPU would show a constant 100% usage. OP clearly states this is not the case.

Comment: Well, you could argue that - but likewise I could argue that OP only mentions that GTA uses 8% of total PP. If you look at the image I posted, you can e.g. see the individual consumption of PP for each task. But I get your point, and I think (rethinking OP's question) that he is referring to total CPU consumption. But to be fair, OP's phrasing is a bit ambiguous. Thank you for the feedback anyways, appreciated!

Comment: The downvote was issued because this is a vague answer to a vague question.  Additionally, the 4790, is only a Haswell i7 anyways. Increasing the priority won't solve the streaming installer if that's happening

Comment: @TobiasAndersen yes its an i7 processer. and the 8% is the amount of usage power of the installer. the total CPU usage for other applications is about 1% since im not running anything else